# How do I seperate a string a mysql db into two fields?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a leads table that has a field named referrer..which has data like this

```
refferer 
yahoo:fine dining
google:cash register
google:sale systems

google:or sale
http://www.somesite.com/
google:software
```

This data is the php `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but this is all in one field ...is there an easy way to split this up in two fields seperated by the : so the final result should be two fields ...Also the referrer field maybe blank as well

```
refferer                     keyword
yahoo                        fine dining
google                       cash register

google                       sale systems
google                       or sale
http://www.somesite.com/
google                       software
```

I really just need an update statement that will seperate the keyword and insert into the keyword field

i looked at [mysql string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and noticed `SUBSTRING_INDEX` but not sure if that would be the best tool for this task

Comment: Are you trying to avoid splitting `http://www.somesite.com/` into refferrer = `http` and keyword = `//www.somesite.com`?

Comment: Yes I was hoping to skip any full irks and keep them in tact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(referrer, ':', -1) as keyword,SUBSTRING_INDEX(referrer, ':', 1) as referrer FROM table;
```

Comment: Would this not split `http://www.somesite.com/` into keyword = `http` and referrer = `//www.somesite.com/`? Based on the question it looks like that is to be avoided?

Comment: @Tom: substr_index returns for the first match only, so unless any of the "keyword" parts of those strings have `:` in them, this should work fine.

Comment: Nice one. Better at database than at php in my opinion. It may go wrong on that http:// part, but it's already something.

Comment: @TomMac Yes, it is possible to problems occurs due to more then a single ":" char in table.